# Can I use JButtons added to a JToolBar to scroll up and down a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Can I scroll a JPanel using JButtons added to a JToolBar?
When I generate a large number of thumbnails, they don't all fit onto the JPanel. I want to use an up/down arrow JButton to scroll. Can this be done, and if so, how?

NOTE: I am trying to do this without a JScrollPane because I want the custom arrow icons, not a standard scroll bar.

Here is an SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class PicSlider2 {
    private JButton thumbs;
    private JButton[] thumbnails;
    private JLabel picViewer;
    private JPanel thumbPanel;
    private JToolBar toolBar;

public PicSlider2() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Picture Slider");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    picViewer = new JLabel();
    picViewer.setText("Image here");
    picViewer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    picViewer.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    picViewer.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));

    JMenuBar frameMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(frameMenuBar);
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    frameMenuBar.add(file);

    JMenuBar picViewerMenu = new JMenuBar();
    picViewerMenu.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    thumbs = new JButton("THUMBNAILS");//an icon in actual program
    thumbs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,45));
    thumbs.setToolTipText("Thumbnails");
    thumbs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                picViewer.setVisible(false);
                thumbPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20,20));                
                thumbPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50,100,50,30));

                thumbnails = new JButton[30];//example size, chosen so all buttons won't fit on one page
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    thumbnails[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
                    thumbnails[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));                  
                    thumbnails[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                           
                                System.out.println("thumbnail clicked - opens full-size view of pic in the JLabel picViewer");                                  
                            }
                        }); 
                    thumbPanel.add(thumbnails[i]);
                    thumbPanel.setVisible(true); 
                }
                toolBar = new JToolBar(null, JToolBar.VERTICAL);
                toolBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 30));
                JButton up = new JButton("Up Arrow");
                up.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,60));
                up.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
                            System.out.println("Up Arrow Stub - NEEDS TO SCROLL UP PAGE, as needed");
                        }
                    } );
                JButton down = new JButton("Down Arrow");
                down.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,60));
                down.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
                            System.out.println("Down Arrow Stub - NEEDS TO SCROLL DOWN PAGE, as needed");
                        }
                    } );
                toolBar.add(Box.createGlue());
                toolBar.add(up);
                toolBar.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(40));
                toolBar.add(down);
                toolBar.add(Box.createGlue());
                frame.getContentPane().add(thumbPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            }
        });
    picViewerMenu.add(thumbs);
    frame.getContentPane().add(picViewerMenu, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(picViewer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setLocation(300, 50);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PicSlider2 ps = new PicSlider2();
            }
        });
}
```

}

Comment: Install a custom look and feel for the scroll pane and let it do its job...

Comment: One of the simplest ways I can think of is to render the contents of the panel to a BufferedImage and then adjust the x/y position at which the image is drawn on the panel...

Comment: Great input, I haven't played much with making a custom look and feel, so this should be fun to figure out. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve your desired result by reordering the items on the JPanel. The JFrame needs to be declared outside of the constructor. I added an index variable for tracking the scroll position and a reloadThumbs() method for reloading the reordered thumbs.
This is the entire code after the changes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class PicSlider2 {
    private JButton thumbs;
    private JButton[] thumbnails;
    private JLabel picViewer;
    private JPanel thumbPanel;
    private JToolBar toolBar;
    private int scrollIndex;
    private final JFrame frame;
public PicSlider2() {
    scrollIndex = 0;
    frame = new JFrame("Picture Slider");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    picViewer = new JLabel();
    picViewer.setText("Image here");
    picViewer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    picViewer.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    picViewer.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));

    JMenuBar frameMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(frameMenuBar);
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    frameMenuBar.add(file);

    JMenuBar picViewerMenu = new JMenuBar();
    picViewerMenu.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    thumbs = new JButton("THUMBNAILS");//an icon in actual program
    thumbs.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,45));
    thumbs.setToolTipText("Thumbnails");
    thumbs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                picViewer.setVisible(false);
                thumbPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 20,20));                
                thumbPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50,100,50,30));

                thumbnails = new JButton[30];//example size, chosen so all buttons won't fit on one page
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                    thumbnails[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
                    thumbnails[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));                  
                    thumbnails[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                           
                                System.out.println("thumbnail clicked - opens full-size view of pic in the JLabel picViewer");                                  
                            }
                        }); 
                    thumbPanel.add(thumbnails[i]);
                    thumbPanel.setVisible(true); 
                }
                toolBar = new JToolBar(null, JToolBar.VERTICAL);
                toolBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 30));
                JButton up = new JButton("Up Arrow");
                up.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,60));
                up.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
                            System.out.println("Up Arrow Stub - NEEDS TO SCROLL UP PAGE, as needed");
                            if(scrollIndex > 3) scrollIndex -= 4;
                            else scrollIndex = 0;
                            reloadThumbs();
                        }
                    } );
                JButton down = new JButton("Down Arrow");
                down.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,60));
                down.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
                            System.out.println("Down Arrow Stub - NEEDS TO SCROLL DOWN PAGE, as needed");
                            if(scrollIndex < 27) scrollIndex += 4;
                            else scrollIndex = 30;
                            reloadThumbs();
                        }
                    } );
                toolBar.add(Box.createGlue());
                toolBar.add(up);
                toolBar.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(40));
                toolBar.add(down);
                toolBar.add(Box.createGlue());
                frame.getContentPane().add(thumbPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            }
        });
        picViewerMenu.add(thumbs);
        frame.getContentPane().add(picViewerMenu, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(picViewer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocation(300, 50);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void reloadThumbs(){
        thumbPanel.removeAll();
        for(int i = scrollIndex; i < 30; ++i){
            thumbPanel.add(thumbnails[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < scrollIndex; ++i){
            thumbPanel.add(thumbnails[i]);
        }
        thumbPanel.revalidate();            
        frame.revalidate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    PicSlider2 ps = new PicSlider2();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: @trackerrr, `I like the algorithm for reloading the buttons` - I find it inconsistent. When you scroll down it sort of wraps the first time you reach the bottom, but the second time you reach the bottom it doesn't wrap. This is confusing. You should either support wrapping or not.

Comment: @camickr - That's fair, I probably should have been more clear in my comment. I like the (very generalized) algorithm that I got from the code: a)when an arrow button is clicked, increment or decrement an integer variable by the number of buttons that fit in a row b)populate panel starting at the array index corresponding to that integer variable. More to your point, for my implementation I did have to modify the above code so that it only scrolls down to the last index of the array and does not wrap. Sorry for the unclear comment.

Comment: @trackerrr, I also question the approach where you are continually by "repopulating" a panel. This is a lot of extra work behind the scenes. No only do you need your custom code, but every time you do this you need to invoke the layout manager so the location of each component can be determined. No other Swing component works like this. Complex components like a JTextArea, JTable, JTree, just use the scroll pane and let the viewport determine what part of the component to display. Anyway, to each his own.

Comment: I also question this approach.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to do this without a JScrollPane because I want the custom arrow icons

You can use a `JScrollPane` and use the default scroll `Action` to create a button with your custom `Icon`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ScrollPaneSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public ScrollPaneSSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        JTable table = new JTable(50, 5);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        add(scrollPane);
        JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();

        JPanel east = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JButton north = new JButton(  new ActionMapAction("UP", vertical, "negativeUnitIncrement") );
        east.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton south = new JButton( new ActionMapAction("DOWN", vertical, "positiveUnitIncrement") );
        east.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollPaneSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ScrollPaneSSCCE());
        frame.setSize(200, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You will need the [Action Map Action](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/action-map-action/) class which is just a simple wrapper class that gets the default `Action` from the `ActionMap` of the specified component.

You will need to set the scroll increment for you panel. Since your image size is 100 you might want to use:

```
vertical.setUnitIncrement( 100 );
```

Comment: Now THAT is a cool class (Action Map Action), can't wait to play around with it as the utility seems huge.  Thank you for the response!